# perl: print $1, $2...till the end

Tags: perl

How to print $3,$5,$7,...$n till the end?

For input: "ab3+cd1+cd2+cd3+cd4+cd5" from argument
Required Output: "cd1 cd2 cd3 cd4 cd5 "

My code goes like this:

```
$num=3;
if ($ARGV[0] =~ /(ab\d)(\+(cd\d))?+/i) {
    while(${$num}) {
        print ${$num}, " ";
        $num += 2;
    }
}
```

My output: (warning/error) Can't use string ("3") as a SCALAR ref while "strict refs" in use at ...

With what change in the code should i get the desired result?

Comment: print $1, " " while $ARGV[0] =~ /\+((cd\d))?+/ig;

Answer (score 5):

One way:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;


my @arr=split(/\+/,$ARGV[0]);
print join " ",@arr[1..$#arr];
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest possible way to put this would be something like:

```
my @args = $ARGV[0] =~ /cd\d+/g;
print "@args";
```

When using the `/g` modifier without capture groups, capturing parentheses are implied around the entire match, and a list of matches are returned.

When interpolating an array in a double quoted string, the values are separated by space (or whatever the value of the `$"` variable).

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
my @matchedwords;
push (@matchedwords, $1) while ($ARGV[0] =~ /(\+cd\d+)/ig);
print "@matchedwords";
```